# Impossible to select a specific SDK into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've a problem with Android Studio.

With SDK manager, I downloaded all Android SDK into the folder "/home/benoit/Android/SDK/android-sdk-linux"

I unpacked android studio into "/home/benoit/android-studio"

Into Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure > Android SDK I set "Android SDK Location" with the path "/home/benoit/Android/SDK/android-sdk-linux"

But on the left, I don't have "SDKs tab" and so I can't choose a specific SDK

Do you know how can I fix it?

EDIT: I add a comment with picture

Comment: SDK Manager : http://postimg.org/image/vf6otduvr/full/
SDK Folder  : http://postimg.org/image/kgbulzf8f/full/
Porject structure :  http://postimg.org/image/wj4q2ubm5/full/

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: This is just an duplicate of your previous question

Comment: Yes that's right, I thought I had may not have properly explained the last time

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "..." button on the right of the SDK Location field, and browse to the location of the SDK you want to use